# Conversion problem from string to int. (String from pair of 2d vector)

Tags: c++, static-cast

Cannot convert
      `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` to `int` without
      a conversion operator
    `int xxx = static_cast<int>(full_list[i][0].second);`

I am trying to convert string from my `vector< vector<pair <int, string> > >` to `int`, but i am getting this error. I tried to use `atoi()`. But it did not help

Comment: Please post the code snippet that you have tried, makes it easier to understand the issue

Comment: btw for an std::string, use `stoi` instead.